# Determine PeopleSoft URL

Tags: peoplesoft

What is the simpliest way to determine the URL of the current component?

What I need to do is take the current URL and change the last part to be a different 
component, which I am storing in a URL definition.  This new URL will be sent thru
email to another OPRID.

But currently am unable to determine the  current URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better building the URL using one of the Generate Functions:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18083_01/pt851pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcr/book.htm?File=tpcr/htm/tpcr22.htm#H3019

Using something like [GenerateComponentPortalURL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18083_01/pt851pbr0/eng/psbooks/tpcl/chapter.htm?File=tpcl/htm/tpcl02.htm#g037ee99c9453fb39_ef90c_10c791ddc07__3d7a) might be better than sub-stringing the different parts together.

Duncan

Edit: Also strCurrUrl gives you the current URL if you can insert some JavaScript

Comment: This function worked great!  Adding in the keys for the component did exactly what I wanted, sent the link in an email and that person has to sign in and is taken right to the component with keys loaded, they are looking directly at the data I wanted them to be looking at.